# What does this syntax mean in js?

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
const List = connect(mapStateToProps)(connectedList);
```

There is a function called "connect" being called with "mapStateToProps" as the argument, however there is "connectedList" surrounded by parenthesis right after the function calling. I haven't seen that before and I didn't find anything about that in the es6 articles I read for research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `connect` function most likely returns another function that accepts one argument which is being invoked.

```js
function getFunc(arg){
  alert(arg);
  return function(arg2){
    alert(arg2);
  }
}
getFunc("arg1")("arg2");//invokes the getFunc function and invokes the returned function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought it was a new syntax quirk but it's actually basic javascript functionality. I just never thought it would be so simple so I was actively searching for new stuff added to modern javascript.

Comment: @PedroRodriguez No problem.